# Rails 5.1.5 - 500 Errors Without Info In Logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, apache, digital-ocean

I am running a Rails 5.1.5 app with webpacker 3.2.2, postgres 9.4, apache2, and passenger. I am not sure what other info is relevant here but can edit as necessary.

My app works locally in development. After I deploy to the server, it will work but eventually gives a 500 error on certain pages from 2 different model/controller actions.

Here is the access log that does not give much info:

```
71.143.443.562 - - [28/Feb/2018:19:15:11 -0700] "GET /posts/jewelry-appraisals-got-even-easier HTTP/1.1" 500 497 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,$
```

I am not sure why and do not know how to reproduce the error (or where to find it). Any ideas? Thank you!

Update - 
Here is the apache2 error.log

```
[ N 2018-02-28 15:56:07.0526 1243/T3 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:917 ]: Checking whether to disconnect long-running connections for process 1416, application /var/www/sellmyjewelry/current (productio$
```

here is my rails production.log:

```
I, [2018-03-01T02:59:04.227988 #6241]  INFO -- : [a45553e8-7b89-45ad-ba05-dade585c17d4] Completed 401 Unauthorized in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
F, [2018-03-01T02:59:04.228965 #6241] FATAL -- : [a45553e8-7b89-45ad-ba05-dade585c17d4]
F, [2018-03-01T02:59:04.229058 #6241] FATAL -- : [a45553e8-7b89-45ad-ba05-dade585c17d4] NoMethodError (To respond to a custom format, register it as a MIME type first: http://guides.rubyonrails.org$
F, [2018-03-01T02:59:04.229093 #6241] FATAL -- : [a45553e8-7b89-45ad-ba05-dade585c17d4]
F, [2018-03-01T02:59:04.229149 #6241] FATAL -- : [a45553e8-7b89-45ad-ba05-dade585c17d4] actionpack (5.1.5) lib/abstract_controller/collector.rb:26:in `method_missing
```

'
Update #2
I made it so all the errors are local. I get a "Mime-Type" error on pages that use the method .html_safe on longer pieces of content. I added mime types in the initialize file but still get the error.

Here is a screenshot of the error I get:
[image]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If your site works in general and this only happens to two actions then the problems are there. Do these same actions cause errors in development?

Comment: The site works in development without any errors. In production, after I initially deploy or restart the server, there are no errors. However, after awhile, the 500 errors occur.

Comment: This is apache access log, are you sure apache error logs are empty?

Comment: You can try to set the log level to debug in production.rb so you can see all the errors `config.log_level = :debug`

Comment: I tried that and making it so all errors are local. It yielded the error message above.